# How do I get into my BIOS without a black screen?

Tags: bios

On my Gigabyte Ultra Durable Series motherboard, how do I get into my BIOS? I hold delete upon start-up, but I get a black screen. I did some digging online and one source said it was because of having on-board graphics along with a PCIe card. I disabled my PCIe (GTX 970) card but I still got a black screen. I am trying to enable Intel VT-x to use Virtual Machines (I have an i7-3820, so it is supported).

Comment: Remove the pcie card.

Comment: How did you disable your onboard graphics?

Comment: @RACING121 I just disabled my graphics card, not my onboard graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to enter the bios/uefi should never be "held" the routine that looks for the "keypress" would miss it completely if it is held in one state. therefore you attack (spam) the button. Another option is to hit the button the moment after you hear the motherboard speaker beep, assuming you have a speaker connected to the motherboard which comes in very handy.

If "fast Boot" or ultra fast or whatever is turned on , the motherboard won't even bother to look for your keypress at all.
If your stuck without an OS where you can change fast boot in the "fastboot" application in the app center, then your back to clearing the cmos , or using the second bios found on such boards. Then remaking your settings, and avoiding turning on ultrafast booting.

There are other odd methods that you can do that will get a board like asus or gig into showing the bios entry info and not proceeding. Slam the power off 2 times before it finishes post, it will think that the present settings are screwed up and that it will not post, and ask you to get into the bios/uefi and change them.

I can think of no reason where the existance or lack of existance or use of  or disabling either GPU device would keep you from getting into the bios, although variations of that could keep you from viewing it once it is there. Solution that by plugging the monitor in anywhere :-) you get the view of the bios, until you work it out.

Not sure you provided enough information about your problem here, there are more than one Gig UD boards?
 When you say "black screen" is there some assumption that you are heading into the bios/uefi but it is not showing?  or you never got that far?
Any other information about the state of the computer before or after, or any background as to what else is working or not would be important to also put in your question. it is hard to understand from what you didnt say if your just configuring it, or it was all working and your just trying to make a change.
If your having issues seeing (black screen) then you should also provide detailed information about how the monitor is hooked up and other important info for determining your setup.

Comment: I disabled hibernation (to disable fast start-up) but I still cannot launch into my BIOS. I tried tapping the key once in different start-up sequences but it booted up into Windows. I held it down for 5 seconds but still got the same black screen.

Comment: The fast boot I was referring to is a bios/uefi feature of newer motherboards. In this situation you have here what the OS itself is doing makes no difference, although if you are still getting into the OS fine, you could turn off ultrafast boot using the supplied gigabyte software called "FastBoot" if that was the problem. You can also use it to access the bios (sort of) right from the OS [Enter Bios Now].  But you still have not supplied the way more information needed to answer correct.  Where is your monitor connected now? had you previously disabled Igpu in the bios? then clear the cmos.

Comment: My monitor is connected straight to my graphics card via DisplayPort. My GPU had not been disabled the last time I got into my BIOS.

Comment: Ahh, if you have any way to connect via vga or dvi that might help to see.  DP is less "legasy" then the older connections, it should still show (be drivered by) the bios , but could be that piece of information is very important to Add (edit) Into Your Question